# How to derive phase margin and gain margin from experimental step response?

Tags: transient, step-response, phase-margin

I have a fabricated closed-loop integrated amplifier circuit. Therefore, I can only conduct transient response experiments. How Do I derive the phase margin and gain margin from the experimental step response?

Comment: You probably can't. If it was possible to derive PM and GM by only step response scope images then Bode100 or similar products wouldn't exist today. You can, however, have an "idea" but not exact numbers (e.g. the overshoot amount and damping may give a clue about PM). You can still measure PM and GM though if you have a waveform generator and a wide BW scope.

Comment: Is it unity feedback?

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible to approximate your amplifier as a 2nd order system then:

[image: equations]

Comment: Now I see I misunderstood the OP. It was about the overall sustem, not the compensator's properties, relative to the plant. +1. But since you're posting a picture, you need to add a link for the source, [to avoid plagiarism](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I created that image myself using Circuit Wizard.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing at least one of the plant or the compensator, no, you can't. That's because you can have two, different plants which, after compensation, can have the exact same response, making it impossible to tell which one is which.

To give an exmaple, consider this plant, \$G_1(s)\$, and its compensator, \$H_1(s)\$ (don't give it too much thought about the numbers, other than it is meant for showing):

$$\begin{align}
G_1(s)&=\dfrac{1}{s+1} \\
H_1(s)&=1+\dfrac1s
\end{align}$$

Given that G is in the forward path and H in the (negative) feedback path, the overall transfer function will be:

$$F_1(s)=\dfrac{G_1(s)}{1+G_1(s)H_1(s)}=\dfrac{s}{s^2+2s+1} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Now let's say there is a second plant, \$G_2(s)\$, different than \$G_1(s)\$, which needs a compensation that will make its output exactly the same as \$F_1(s)\$. For that, solve for \$H_1(s)\$ in \$\eqref{1}\$, rename it \$H_2(s)\$, keep \$F_1(s)\$ as it is (since that is the goal), and then replace \$G_1(s)\rightarrow G_2(s)\$, to give the required compensation:

$$H_2(s)=\dfrac{G_2(s)-F_1(s)}{G_2(s)F_1(s)}=1+\dfrac1s \tag{2}\label{2}$$

Funny enough, it's identical to \$H_1(s)\$. Now let's test it:

[image: different G, same response]

To the right you can see the two plants, whose responses are plotted in the top plot. By themselves, they are different. The left side has the two closed loops, whose difference is plotted in the middle plot, showing a flat difference (save initial numerical mismatches, until the loops "kick in", given that the underlying systems are different), while the bottom plot shows the two overall responses, side-by-side, quite overlapped.

Would you be able to tell which one is which, or GM & PM, given only the output responses?

You can create many such cases with the same method. Just for the fun of it, even \$1/(s^2+s+1)\$ could be compensated by a (rather impractical) \$1+1/s-s^2\$ to give the same response as above. Feel free to try it. Or, if the plant is a generic 2nd order lowpass, \$1/(s^2+as+1)\$, what would this compensator do to its reponse: \$s(1-a)-(2/3)s^2\$?